# ITextSharp, won't add second row to PdfPTable

Tags: c#, itext

I'm trying to add a header and footer to my PDF using an ITextEvent,

My `OnEndPage` method is shown below.

The following line:

```
pdfTab.AddCell(pdfCell3);
```

is throwing an error *"Object reference not sent to instance of an object"*

The other two cells add fine and the pdf renders properly if I don't add the 3rd cell.

```
public override void OnEndPage(iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter writer, iTextSharp.text.Document document)
{
     base.OnEndPage(writer, document);

    BaseFont Calibri = BaseFont.CreateFont(@"C:\windows\fonts\calibri.ttf", BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
    BaseFont CalibriBold = BaseFont.CreateFont(@"C:\windows\fonts\calibrib.ttf", BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);

    Font baseFontSmall = new Font(Calibri, 10, Font.BOLD, Color.BLACK);
     Font baseFontNormal = new Font(Calibri, 12, Font.NORMAL, Color.BLACK);
     Font baseFontBig = new Font(CalibriBold, 12, Font.BOLD, Color.BLACK);


    Phrase p1Header = new Phrase("Sample Header Here", baseFontNormal);

    //Create PdfTable object
    PdfPTable pdfTab = new PdfPTable(2);


     create separate cells to include image logo and 2 separate strings
    //Row 1
    PdfPCell pdfCell1 = new PdfPCell();
    PdfPCell pdfCell2 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Doctors name", baseFontNormal));

    //row2
    PdfPCell pdfCell3 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Date and stuff", baseFontNormal));



    pdfCell1.Colspan = 1;
    pdfCell2.Colspan = 1;
    pdfCell3.Colspan = 2;


    String text = "Page " + writer.PageNumber + " of ";


    //Add paging to footer
    {
        cb.BeginText();
        cb.SetFontAndSize(bf, 10);
        cb.SetTextMatrix(document.PageSize.GetRight(180), document.PageSize.GetBottom(30));
        cb.ShowText(text);
        cb.EndText();
        float len = bf.GetWidthPoint(text, 12);
        cb.AddTemplate(footerTemplate, document.PageSize.GetRight(180) + len, document.PageSize.GetBottom(30));
    }



    //set the alignment of all three cells and set border to 0
    pdfCell1.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
    pdfCell2.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT;
    pdfCell3.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT;
    //pdfCell4.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT;

    pdfCell2.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_TOP;
    pdfCell3.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_BOTTOM;
    pdfCell1.Border = 0;
    pdfCell2.Border = 0;
    pdfCell3.Border = 0;


    //add all three cells into PdfTable
    pdfTab.AddCell(pdfCell1);
    pdfTab.AddCell(pdfCell2);
    pdfTab.AddCell(pdfCell3);

    pdfTab.TotalWidth = document.PageSize.Width - 80f;
    pdfTab.WidthPercentage = 70;



    //call WriteSelectedRows of PdfTable. This writes rows from PdfWriter in PdfTable
    //first param is start row. -1 indicates there is no end row and all the rows to be included to write
    //Third and fourth param is x and y position to start writing
    pdfTab.WriteSelectedRows(0, -1, 40, document.PageSize.Height - 30, writer.DirectContent);
    //set pdfContent value

    //Move the pointer and draw line to separate header section from rest of page
    cb.MoveTo(40, document.PageSize.Height - 100);
    cb.LineTo(document.PageSize.Width - 40, document.PageSize.Height - 100);
    cb.Stroke();

    //Move the pointer and draw line to separate footer section from rest of page
    cb.MoveTo(40, document.PageSize.GetBottom(50));
    cb.LineTo(document.PageSize.Width - 40, document.PageSize.GetBottom(50));
    cb.Stroke();
}
```

Stack Trace

```
at iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfPRow.set_RTL(Boolean value)
at iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfPTable.AddCell(PdfPCell cell)
at ITextEvents.OnEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document) in c:\TFS\PSA\Source           Code\App_Code\ITextEvents.cs:line 145

at iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfDocument.NewPage()
at PhysComp.UI.CreateSummaryReports.WritePdfLine(Tbl_ProvidersRecord NameRecord, PdfContentByte& Cb, BaseFont Font, Int32 FontSize, Int32 Alignment, String text, Int32 xPos, Int32& yindex, Int32 rotation) in c:\TFS\PSA\Source Code\SummaryReport\CreateSummaryReports.aspx.cs:line 346

at PhysComp.UI.CreateSummaryReports.printInvoice(PdfContentByte& Cb, Int32& yindex, Tbl_ProvidersRecord NameRecord, Invoices_By_CheckRecord invoice, Dictionary`2 ChequeAmounts) in c:\TFS\PSA\Source Code\SummaryReport\CreateSummaryReports.aspx.cs:line 295

at PhysComp.UI.CreateSummaryReports.printInvoices(PdfContentByte& Cb, Int32& yindex, Tbl_ProvidersRecord NameRecord, List`1 Invoices, Dictionary`2 ChequeAmounts) in c:\TFS\PSA\Source Code\SummaryReport\CreateSummaryReports.aspx.cs:line 272

 at PhysComp.UI.CreateSummaryReports.CreatePDF(Tbl_ProvidersRecord NameRecord, DateTime StartDate, DateTime EndDate) in c:\TFS\PSA\Source Code\SummaryReport\CreateSummaryReports.aspx.cs:line 133
```

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this. Do you have more to work with? A full stack trace perhaps? Or a more detailed error message?

Comment: @MichaëlDemey The Stack trace has been added above

Comment: I also tried your code exactly and there were no errors. Since you're using `Color.BLACK` I'm guessing you're not using the modern version, right? Are you using 4.1.6? I would start my removing things slowly until it compiles. Start with the `cb` stuff since that shouldn't have anything to do with the table. Then try getting rid of all of the alignment and spanning things. Keep going and try to get the code to the smallest amount that still throws an exception and update it above.